# google maps api v3: where is the load event

Tags: events, api, google-maps

Which event will do the same that the load event did on the api v2 spec?

Right after the map is initialized, calling to getBounds().getSouthWest() will return null.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no load event. Perhaps you want `'idle'`

Comment: Yes, it works, but it is not what I was needing: 'idle' will fire several times, and not only once after everything has finished loading for the 1st time. I eneded up attaching the event to idle, and keeping track of whether I already done what I was trying to do 'onload'.

Comment: In that case, use `addListenerOnce` :)

Comment: Ha, yes! addListenerOnce is what I needed. Thanks